# Run multiple startup projects from command line

Tags: windows, visual-studio, azure

I have a Visual Studio solution that, when started, runs multiple projects.

This is achieved following the instructions in the [ms docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx).

Is there a way to run those same startup projects via command line?